# Replacing ubunto with windows (any at this point)

Tags: boot, system-installation, windows

I hope you're all doing well!

**TL/DR version:**

- Need to install windows over ubunto;
- Windows isn't recognising any drives;
- Tried using a live udunto pen to use Gparted to format the drives to NTFS and eliminate the ext4 partitions;
- Windows isn't recognising any drives still;
- Tried again the live ubunto pen and this time got Gparted to leave the drives as unallocated space;
- Windows isn't recognising any drives still;

Besides pulling the drives off the laptop to do an external format, any ideas or pointers please? :)

**Long version with sprinkles on top ;) :**

I've been having quite a frustrating experience with Windows lately, to the point where it almost feels like it's punishing me for daring to install Ubuntu (which only fuels me more in wanting to learn this SO to a point where i don't need windows anymore). However, before I can fully master or even become proficient in the Ubuntu operating system, I still have some school work to submit. I'm currently studying programming and going through a major career change, so I'm not quite at that level yet, but I'm working hard to get there. Once I complete this work, I still plan on installing Ubuntu alongside Windows in a dual-boot configuration, as it seems to be the best and most common practice(typically, Windows first, followed by Linux).

A brief overview of the issue I'm facing and the steps I've taken so far:

1. Initially, I installed Ubuntu over Windows 11 as a trial run while I was waiting for some laptop parts to upgrade my system. I wanted to experience Ubuntu natively rather than using a virtual machine since I planned on wiping the system anyway.
2. After I received the parts and upgraded my rig, I attempted to install Windows over Ubuntu. Unfortunately, Windows didn't detect any drives available for installation.
3. I did some research and came across a similar problem on a forum. One of the suggested solutions was to use a live Ubuntu USB and run Gparted to format the drives completely to NTFS, eliminating the ext4 partitions. I tried this approach, but it didn't solve the issue.
4. I delved deeper into the forum post and found another user suggesting an external format of the drives instead. However, I haven't tried this option yet, as I'm hoping to find a softer solution. It would require me to obtain an SSD M.2 to USB adapter.
5. I reached out to two of my professors who are knowledgeable about Linux systems—one specializing in Debian (open-source and server configuration) and the other in Ubuntu (web development client side). They both seemed surprised by the error I encountered. However, they agreed that I should try using a live Ubuntu USB again, but this time leave the drives as unallocated space. They suggested that the previous formatting of the drives using Gparted in a Linux OS might have altered the partition tables in a way that Windows doesn't recognize. I followed their advice, but unfortunately, it didn't resolve the issue.

Aside from option/step 4. I would greatly appreciate any ideas or pointers you may have for me to explore.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

**EDITs:**

- corrected some misspellings;
- Added TL/DR;

Comment: It is unclear what the actual problem is? (Question is TL/DR, please share the top problem in the fist paragraph, skip all the bla-bla about professors, "frustrating experience" and "fully master or even become proficient".

Comment: @Luuk Just edited it and added a TL/DR version, hope it gelps to get the point across. Cheers for the feedback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: Windows 11 is UEFI and requires gpt partitioning. Is drive gpt? And it requires a lot of partitions. BIOS & UEFI Windows partitions, note system has totally different format  & meaning between BIOS & UEFI
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations & 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx & 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thank you for the info, but sadly no it doesn't. It was one of the first posts i looked into. They go into detail on removing udunto from a Dual boot set up and the only references to a single boot are as simple as installing over the Ubunto OS, which is the part I'm having issues with.

Comment: @oldfred If you're referring to the pen I'm using to install windows yes, I used rufus to create the pen with windows 11 with GTP formating. The drives are formated to unalocated space (like they would be out of the box to my understanding). And the laptop is BIOS: InsydeH20 Rev. 5.0 (hope this info helps) Is this the issue? How to go about it?

Comment: Thank you, @Nmath, for your input. I understand that the issue I'm facing is not directly related to Ubuntu itself. However, as I'm eager to become a part of the Linux community, I was under the impression that Linux users are generally welcoming and open to assisting with various problems or issues, even if they pertain to getting Linux to work alongside other operating systems. That's why I reached out for help here. Nonetheless, I do acknowledge that troubleshooting Windows installation problems falls outside the scope of this community. I appreciate your clarification.

Comment: Please run GParted and put screenshots of all the disk partitions into your question.

Comment: We'd certainly be able to help if/when you are installing Ubuntu or if you have an Ubuntu problem or question about working alongside another operating system. Ask Ubuntu is actively moderated and questions should fit the scope and format of our site.  See https://askubuntu.com/tour and https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic | A lot of our users also use the sister site, Super User, where Windows installation questions are on topic there

Comment: And thank you @Nmath,definitely got me to ask the right questions as well. Although windows support wasn't very helpful all over the place in terms of answers and the driver no where to be seen (guess it's not only the installer that can't find the drivers it needs :P). Still think i came to the right place, thank you all. ;)

Comment: @Raffles I got it to work with Sameer Trivedi suggestion. I think it was really as some people suggested. It wasn't an issue with the SSD formatting, but a question of getting windows to recognise the ssd drive and getting it to speak to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an Intel CPU, you will need Intel Rapid Storage drivers for windows to be able to detect the drives.
This link has instructions on how to do that:
https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1044458/

PS: The file system of the drive should have nothing to do with installers being able to detect it in majority of the cases. If it understands the driver, it should show the drive.

Comment: Thank you. :) I'll look into that.

Comment: Definitely pointed me into the right direction and started asking the right questions. Cheers and thank you so much. ;)
Had to go my acer model specific drivers, but windows is recognising the SSDs now.

Comment: Now to install Ubunto in dual boot mode hell yeahhh.